# A stays to something as B stays to something

Tags: british-english

I need to use a sentence to describe a young talent. If I had to translate it literally from my language it would say "John stays to Chess as Mozart stays to Music". (Obviously meaning a basic equation).
Is that correct in English?
Thanks

Comment: My own native tongue uses a similar verb in those comparisons, but in English I think the simplest way to convey the equation is _John is to chess what Mozart is to music_.

Comment: What @oerkelens said, as long as your intent is to say, “John is a chess prodigy to the same degree as Mozart was a music prodigy.”

Comment: @Jim: "prodigy" (or any other positive description) is possible, but not required. The same sentence would be correct if both John and Mozart e.g. made a mockery of their respective fields. You might say "but Mozart was well loved", but I've heard opinions that Mozart is unjustly hailed as the poster child for musical talent. The underlying reasons are not important, but it is important to note that if the speaker thinks that Mozart is overrated (even if that's not commonly understood), then the speaker is also calling John overrated, and the sentence remains correct.

Comment: @Flater - Of course, but in this particular case Mozart was a prodigy.  (my comment was because the “stays to” could also be interpreted as “sticks to” as in John sticks to Chess- meaning John knows he’s good at Chess and so doesn’t try to play other games.

Comment: @Jim: _You_ know Mozart as an undeniably prodigy. But again, the speaker may not agree with you. You can't assume that your opinion on Mozart is guaranteed to be the intended message of the speaker. **Regardless** of opinions, we can agree that it's grammatically correct, no matter which trait the speaker is referring to (positive or negative).

Comment: @Flater - You miss my point.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I recall the expression "John is to chess what Mozart is to music", thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Unless there is a highly idiomatic usage of the original word for 'stay' which is mistranslated here as 'stay', @Jim's analysis is much more plausible. "John sticks to Chess just like Mozart stuck to Music".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it demands an understanding of the original.

Comment: John stands in relation to chess as Mozart stands in relation to music.  OP's "stays" may have much in common with this sense of "stands".

Comment: Your language being Italian?

Comment: One thing is to another as a third thing is to a fourth. No need to understand any other language.

Answer (score 1):

As @oerkelens mentions in the comments, "is to" is the correct phrase. You can also write it mathematic-like: John : Chess :: Mozart : Music.

Comment: Don't write it mathematically!

Answer (score 1):

> John is to Chess as Mozart is to Music

Comment: Welcome to the ELL. One sentece answers are discouraged on this site. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how to answer more thoroughly.